# Link to local contents

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Can someone please tell me how to make an image saved in Data Folder an icon in Mozilla Add-on Builder.

I tried:

```
data = require('self').data
contentUrl : data.url(filename)
```

What did I do wrong?

**Update**

It worked well when the image is of type *.png* but for the type *.ico* . I really have no clue what happens in the background.

Can someone help??

Comment: I assume that you are using the `widget` module but decided to omit this fact to make the question more intriguing? You are quoting an example [from documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.10/packages/addon-kit/widget.html) and it definitely works - so the problem must be elsewhere, not in the code you show here.

Comment: agreed, please add more info. If, for example, you are trying to reference something in the data folder in package.jsopn, that won't work. package.json is not run as JS. Icons referred to in package.json need to be store in the root directory of your add-on project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume omitting the `;`'s at the end of lines was also for intrigue.

I find that when the file is something other than a 16x16 .ico file, the add-on will be painfully slow and the mouse cursor will disappear.  Maybe that's just a Linux thing, or something else peculiar to my setup.